# Will a cookie whose samesite=none and secure=true not set from Chrome 80?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I know the behavior about cookie is changed from chrome 80.
https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html

This blog says, "When the SameSite=None attribute is present, an additional Secure attribute must be used so cross-site cookies can only be accessed over HTTPS connections."
Is this meaning that the cookie whose SameSite=None and Secure=False will be rejected by Chrome? Can't we set such a cookie?

I couldn't read that way.

However, in the test way which is written in this blog also indicates, 
the description says "it will be rejected".

> **Cookies without SameSite must be secure**
>
> If enabled, cookies without SameSite restrictions must also be Secure.
>   If a cookie without SameSite restrictions is set without the Secure
>   attribute, it will be rejected. This flag only has an effect if
>   "SameSite by default cookies" is also enabled. – Mac, Windows, Linux,
>   Chrome OS, Android

Is this correct behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. If you are setting `SameSite=None` it **must** always be `Secure`. If you do not set `Secure`, the cookie will be rejected.

Chrome makes two flags available for early testing:

- `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` - this flag will treat cookies without a `SameSite` attribute as if they had `SameSite=Lax`.
- `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure` - this flag will cause cookies with `SameSite=None` but missing `Secure` to be rejected.

While these are two separate changes from a Chrome implementation point of view, developers should look to address this as one change. Review existing cookies and set the appropriate `SameSite` and `Secure` attributes where possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood.

Comment: Is this affected all cookies whether first-party cookie or third-party?

Comment: Whether a cookie is first or third party is just down to the context of the request. When a cookie is set with `SameSite=None; Secure` it will be sent on same-site (first party) and cross-site (third-party) requests.

Comment: @rowan_m as youv'e suggested Iv'e updated my cookie to have the flags SameSite=None; Secure.  Seems like since the last chrome update on some computers (same chrome versions) it saves the cookies as `same-site connections only`. are you familiar with the problem?

Comment: This will not work in Safari samesite=None is also seen as SameSite = strict in safari latest versions Do you guys have any solution ? I couldn`t change browser settting I have to perform task with default setting of safari .